# What is this syntax in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

```
    type JSXElementConstructor<P> =
        | ((props: P) => ReactElement<any, any> | null)
        | (new (props: P) => Component<any, any>);       => What is this?
```

What is the `new` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((props: P) => ReactElement<any, any> | null)` describes a plain function that, when called, returns a ReactElement.

`(new (props: P) => Component<any, any>)` describes a *class* that, when called with `new`, returns a Component - hence the `new`.

They're not interchangeable . The union lets `JSXElementConstructor` account for both functional components and class components.

For a simple example outside of React of a newable that's assignable to `new () =>`:

```
type X = (new () => { getName: () => string });
class Person {
    #name = 'foo';
    getName() {
        return this.#name;
    }
}

const P: X = Person;
```